# java.io.IOException: error=36, File name too long in java

Tags: java, eclipse, processbuilder

I have a method which executes the linux shell commands using the ProcessBuilder API.But, when i am trying to execute the Runnable Jar created from the eclipse it gives me the error as below. I have gone through many blogs and posts but unable to resolve the issue.

I am using java 1.7

XARGS Command gives me the below info

```
xargs --show-limits
Your environment variables take up 3064 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2616328
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2613264
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072



List<String> list = getList();
            for(Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();itr.hasNext();)
            {

                String command = itr.next();
                System.out.println("Length of String "+command.length());
                LOGGER.info("Executing the command \n"+ command);
                ProcessBuilder processbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
                processbuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
                Process process = processbuilder.start();
                process.waitFor();
            }
```

> : error=36, File name too long
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
>           at com.cisco.parallelexecutor.ParallelExecutor.main(ParallelExecutor.java:35)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=36, File name too long
>           at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:186)
>           at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
>           ... 1 more

Command which i am trying to run

```
SQOOP_XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE=ssh hddev-c01-edge-02 "sqoop import -D mapred.child.java.opts='\-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom' --connect 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=*****.cisco.com)(PORT=&&&&))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=*****.COM)(Server=Dedicated)))' --username *** --password **** --query \"select CONTRACT_ID,CONTRACT_NUMBER,CONTRACT_STS_CODE,CONTRACT_STATUS,SERVICE_LINE_ID,SERVICE_LINE_NAME,SERVICE_LINE_STS_CODE,SERVICE_LINE_STATUS,SERVICE_LINE_NUMBER,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,HDR_PARTY_ID,HDR_CUSTOMER_NAME,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,LINE_PARTY_ID,LINE_CUSTOMER_NAME,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_NAME,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_STS,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_ID,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_NUMBER,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_STS,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_STS,BILL_TO_PARTY_ID,BILL_TO_PARTY_NUMBER,BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_NAME,BILL_TO_PARTY_STS,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_ID,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_STS,BILL_TO_LOCATION_ID,BILL_TO_COUNTRY,BILL_TO_STATE_PROV,BILL_TO_CITY,BILL_TO_POSTAL_CODE,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_ID,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_DESC,COVERAGE_BEGIN_DATE,COVERAGE_END_DATE,SERVICE_SALES_REP_USR_ID,SERVICE_SALES_REP_USR_NAME,SERVICE_LINE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,BILLTO_CSC_ID,BILLTO_CSC_NAME,BILLTO_GU_ID,BILLTO_GU_NAME,BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_SALES_CHANNEL,CURRENCY_CODE,CONTRACT_LIST_AMT,CONTRACT_NET_AMT,USD_CONTRACT_LIST_AMT,USD_CONTRACT_NET_AMT,ACCOUNT_TEAM,RENEWAL_SSR,RENEWAL_TEAM,SALES_REGION,ADVANCE_CONTRACT_FLAG,EARLIEST_END_DATE,SERVICE_LINE_TERMINATED_DATE,SVC_LINE_TERMINATION_REASON,CONTRACT_TERMINATED_DATE,USD_CONV_RATE,PRICE_TYPE,NET_VALUE,COTERM_DATE,MARKETING_PROGRAM,MASTER_AGREEMENT_END_DATE,DISCOUNT_PERCENT,PRORATE_FLAG,RGP_ID,CREATION_DATE,CREATED_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY,LAST_UPDATED_LOGIN,REQUEST_ID,PROGRAM_UPDATE_DATE,PROGRAM_APPLICATION_ID,PROGRAM_ID,ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY,ATTRIBUTE1,ATTRIBUTE2,ATTRIBUTE3,ATTRIBUTE4,ATTRIBUTE5,ATTRIBUTE6,ATTRIBUTE7,ATTRIBUTE8,ATTRIBUTE9,ATTRIBUTE10,ATTRIBUTE11,ATTRIBUTE12,ATTRIBUTE13,ATTRIBUTE14,ATTRIBUTE15,ATTRIBUTE16,ATTRIBUTE17,ATTRIBUTE18,ATTRIBUTE19,ATTRIBUTE20,ACCOUNT_SSR,SHELL_CONTRACT_FLAG,CONTRACT_START_DATE,CONTRACT_END_DATE from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE where \\\$CONDITIONS \" --split-by CONTRACT_NUMBER -m 4 --null-string '\\\\N' --null-non-string '\\\\N' --hive-delims-replacement '<EOL>' --boundary-query 'select (select min(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as minid ,(select max(CONTRACT_NUMBER) from XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE) as maxid from dual' --target-dir /app/dev/SmartAnalytics/sqoop_temp//XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-table installbase.XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE --map-column-hive CONTRACT_ID=BIGINT,SERVICE_LINE_ID=BIGINT,HDR_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID=BIGINT,HDR_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,LINE_CUST_ACCOUNT_ID=BIGINT,LINE_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_SITE_USE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_PARTY_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_PARTY_SITE_ID=BIGINT,BILL_TO_LOCATION_ID=BIGINT,COVERAGE_TEMPLATE_ID=BIGINT,COVERAGE_BEGIN_DATE=TIMESTAMP,COVERAGE_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,SERVICE_LINE_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=BIGINT,BILLTO_CSC_ID=BIGINT,BILLTO_GU_ID=BIGINT,CONTRACT_LIST_AMT=BIGINT,CONTRACT_NET_AMT=BIGINT,USD_CONTRACT_LIST_AMT=BIGINT,USD_CONTRACT_NET_AMT=BIGINT,EARLIEST_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,SERVICE_LINE_TERMINATED_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CONTRACT_TERMINATED_DATE=TIMESTAMP,USD_CONV_RATE=BIGINT,NET_VALUE=BIGINT,MASTER_AGREEMENT_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP,DISCOUNT_PERCENT=BIGINT,PRORATE_FLAG=STRING,RGP_ID=BIGINT,CREATION_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CREATED_BY=BIGINT,LAST_UPDATE_DATE=TIMESTAMP,LAST_UPDATED_BY=BIGINT,LAST_UPDATED_LOGIN=BIGINT,REQUEST_ID=BIGINT,PROGRAM_UPDATE_DATE=TIMESTAMP,PROGRAM_APPLICATION_ID=BIGINT,PROGRAM_ID=BIGINT,ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY=STRING,ATTRIBUTE1=STRING,ATTRIBUTE2=STRING,ATTRIBUTE3=STRING,ATTRIBUTE4=STRING,ATTRIBUTE5=STRING,ATTRIBUTE6=STRING,ATTRIBUTE7=STRING,ATTRIBUTE8=STRING,ATTRIBUTE9=STRING,ATTRIBUTE10=STRING,ATTRIBUTE11=STRING,ATTRIBUTE12=STRING,ATTRIBUTE13=STRING,ATTRIBUTE14=STRING,ATTRIBUTE15=STRING,ATTRIBUTE16=STRING,ATTRIBUTE17=STRING,ATTRIBUTE18=STRING,ATTRIBUTE19=STRING,ATTRIBUTE20=STRING,ACCOUNT_SSR=STRING,SHELL_CONTRACT_FLAG=STRING,CONTRACT_START_DATE=TIMESTAMP,CONTRACT_END_DATE=TIMESTAMP" >> /apps/pentaho_nfs/installbase/input/poc/logs/IB_logs.log 2>&1
```

Length of the String is 4260

Comment: yes it is a meaningless exception.

Comment: "Length of the String is 4260". That's 4.2 KB file name. Are you sure that this doesn't exceed the limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` has two constructors. You're using this one:
[`ProcessBuilder(String... command)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder%28java.lang.String...%29)

The *first* parameter is the command to run, and any *subsequent* parameters are the arguments to the command.

Since you're passing a single string, **the entire string is the command**, aka the program. No command-line arguments given. The error message means exactly what it says: `File name too long`

Split your command into multiple strings, and use the `redirectXxx()` methods to send output to a file.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the OS and the filesystem, but the maximum length of filename that you can reasonably count on portably is generally 1024 characters and the maximum length of any part (between the slashes) is 255.

You didn't mention your OS, but under Linux and NetBSD both, I get:

```
# getconf PATH_MAX /
4096

# getconf NAME_MAX /
255
```

And on OS X I get:

```
% getconf PATH_MAX /
1024

% getconf NAME_MAX /
255
```

YMMV

Comment: I am using RedHat linux 
getconf PATH_MAX /
4096
getconf NAME_MAX /
255

Comment: You need to construct your command line so that the file name fits within the limits of your system.  Are you expecting a command with that long of a file name (perhaps you are not generating the command you think you are)?

Comment: I think you are not using `new ProcessBuilder()` correctly.  [ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html ] it looks like it wants the command not all in one string like you have it, but broken out into a `List<String>` or as many String args like `command, arg1, arg2, arg3`

Answer (score -2):

Java is lying you.

I get similar problem with a huge command, more than 3000 characters.

But if i get the command copy/paste directlly in the shell it runs perfectly.

Then the problem is not the length of that command, the problem is how Java works with it.

And Yes, Im working witha list of args, and the problem is still the same.

Comment: Please check this[URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to raise your content quality up